# Regex to match PID with grep?

Tags: shell, grep

I want to match `6202/java` or `6202`

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:2014          :::*                    LISTEN      6202/java
```

With regex web tooling I am able to match it but if I use `"\S*$"` regex to match non white space up to the end of the string I get nothing.

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep java | grep -o "\S*$"
```

Comment: With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. `sudo netstat -tulpn | awk 'split($NF,arr,"/")==2 && arr[2]=="java"'{print arr[1],arr[2]}'` and let me know if this helps you. OR 2nd solution as: `sudo netstat -tulpn | awk -F' |/' '$NF=="java"{print $(NF-1),$NF}'` also can be tried.

Comment: What is it that you would like to achieve here? Do you just require the PID of that particular program?

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following codes.

***1st solution:*** Running `netstat` command with `tulpn` options and sending its output to `awk` code. In `awk` code making field separators as either space OR `/` and then checking if last field is `java` then print last 2 fields of that line.

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | 
awk -F' |/' '
 $NF=="java"{
  print $(NF-1),$NF
 }
'
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Running `netstat` command with `tulpn` options and sending its output to `awk` code. In `awk` code using `split` function to split last field with separator as `/` and creating an array named `arr` AND checking further condition if 2nd element of that array is java then print both of the elements of that array OR print last field(which will be last and 2nd last field of that line).

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | 
awk '
split($NF,arr,"/")==2 && arr[2]=="java"'{
  print $NF
}'
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` try following code. Using its -`oP` options to print exact matched value and enabling PCRE regex respectively. In main program matching value till last space occurs followed by a `\K` to forget that matched regex and matching digits(1 or more occurrences) and making sure its followed by `/java` using positive look ahead mechanism.

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep -oP '.*[[:space:]]+\K\d+(?=/java)'
```

Comment: for **2nd solution** since you've already done the verification checks in the pattern space, why not just `print $NF`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto, yeah valid point, I thought of making use of those 2 array elements,, edited it now cheers.

Comment: you've already made good use of them by using them to check for "java" criteria

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto, yeah true, that's why changed it to $NF, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in a somewhat different alternative. The command `lsof` allows you to query based on program name.

```
$ lsof -Pan -i -c java
```

This outputs some tabulated data. If you add `-F string` to it, you can ask it what to output in a way that is easily processable with tools such as awk and sed. The default will just output the pid and file descriptors, so you can do something like:

```
$ lsof -Pan -i -F'' -c java | awk '/^p/{print substr($0,2)}'
```

Details of `lsof` can be found in `man lsof`

Answer (score 0):

You can write the grep command as:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep -o "[^[:space:]]\+java[[:space:]]*$"
```

Using `-o`

> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each
> such part on a separate output line.

The pattern matches:

- `[^[:space:]]\+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `java` Match literally
- `[[:space:]]*` Match optional spaces
- `$` End of string

Output

```
6202/java
```

---

If you want to have the digits only and `-P` is supported for a perl compatible regex you can match 1+ digits and assert `/java` to the right at the end of the string:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep -oP "\d+(?=/java\s*$)"
```

Output

```
6202
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> awk NF++ FS='.* ' OFS=
>
> mawk '$!NF= $NF' 
> gawk  '$_ = $NF'
> ```

```
6202/java
```

That's all u need for last column. To keep only when java is there :

> ```
>  awk 'index($!++NF, "/java")' FS='.* ' OFS=
> mawk '$!NF=$(NF *=/\/java$/)'
> ```

```
6202/java
```

If you don't mind 1 extra leading space :

> ```
> mawk -F'.* ' 'NF*=/\/java$/'
> ```

```
 6202/java
```

And if you ***just*** want the `PID`,

> ```
> mawk 'NF -= /\/java$/' FS='^.* |/' OFS=
> ```

```
6202
```